# Regular expression " symbol is not working

Tags: java, regex

- Password must not match or contain last name.
- Password must contain at least 1 special characters.
- Password must contain at least 1 numeric characters.
- Password must contain at least 2 alphabetic characters.
- Password must contain at least 1 uppercase letters.
- Password must not match or contain user ID.
- Password must not match or contain first name.
- Password must not contain the following characters: !
- Password must not be longer than 25 characters.
- Password must be at least 8 characters long.
- Password must contain at least 1 lowercase letters.

These are the symbols should contain in `!"#$%&'()*+-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~`

but i am trying to put " this special character  it is giving error[compile time error]

```
private static final String PASSWORD_PATTERN = "((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*["@#$%!%^&*()_+=?/[],.<>|~`'-]).{8,32})";
```

Can an one hep , thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried escaping the quote?

Comment: no, i don't how to do this escaping in regular expression

Answer (score 3):

Of course you can't simply put a quote in a string literal, that ends the string. And it's not related to regular expression, that would be the same whatever you do later with the string.

Simply escape it : replace `"` with `\"`

---

Addendum regarding the new question in comments : if you put `[` and `]` in a character class (that is between `[` and `]`), then you must escape them for the regular expression. And as you do that in a string literal, that makes a double escaping because you must escape the `\`. And you must also escape the `-` in a character class.

So change

```
["@#$%!%^&*+=?/[],.<>|~`'-:/<>]
```

to

```
["@#$%!%^&*+=?/\\[\\],.<>|~`'\\-:/<>]
```

Comment: omg
Exception in thread "Main Thread" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 75
((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*["@#$%!%^&*+=?/[],.<>|~`'-:/<>]).{8,32})
                                                                           ^
This is saying not enclosed at the end :(

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use https://www.debuggex.com/ when you are trying to work with regular expressions. It's easier and directly tells you if your regex is incorrect.